# PyCharm: Cannot keep interpreters the same on two different computers when accessing same project

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, project, interpreter

I regularly switch between computers to work on the same project. It has become a headache to have separate interpreters updated with modules installed on my two machines even though both computers can access the net drive where python.exe is placed.

When I try to set the interpreter from my second computer to the same used by my primary computer, I keep getting an Invalid Python SDK error:

[image]

Currently the system python version is 3.9.1. Maybe I should uninstall this and install python3.6?

[image]

I am using Win10 64bit on both computer. My main computer has Intel i5, and my secondary computer (problem) has two Intel Xeon. I have seen posts that suggested edit the PYTHONPATH but do not know where to access it in Win10 so please be specific with the OS.

Comment: You are probably experiencing a problem with binary incompatibility. Is your net drive also 64 bit and running windows?

Comment: What happens if you take Pycharm out of the equation and try to use the remote interpreter directly?

Comment: Please also include the architectures (AMD, Intel, ??) of all computers involved here. Also indicate their word size (64 bit or 32 bit), and what OS they are all running on

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to share an interpreter between the two machines? This seems like a very unusual idea.

"I regularly switch between computers to work on the same project." - this is very common that multiple people work over the same project and instead sharing interpreter, they use specific tools to manage modules and dependencies. I think that you can do the same.

The best way is to use something more sophisticated than the plain requirements.txt - you can check out pipenv which is supported by PyCharm: https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/

Then, you can store pipenv artifacts on your gir repo (you have it, right?) and update packages with a few commands which is described in the above link.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @trivvz. It seems to me that pipenv is more suited for module management across DIFFERENT projects?

Comment: @Penemonie, pipenv can handle different projects because for every project it creates a virtual environment where external packages are installed so you can avoid any conflicts which is a great thing. But you can use it to keep track of the dependencies of a single project thanks to Pipfile and Pipfile.lock. These two files allow you to recreate the same Python environment on every machine for any user